# In Linux, how can I get the absolute path of the Python binary I am using from the command line?

Tags: python, linux, command-line

I find this especially useful when using `pyenv` or `virtualenv`.

Comment: @martijn-pieters Question linked as possible duplicate doesn't really provide a single command line command. Top answer requires dipping into the interpreter.

Comment: Combining that into a one-liner is not really all that hard or novel.

Comment: This is the simplest answer to the quesiton as asked. If the OP had somethign else in mind, perhaps he should update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

Sample output:

```
/home/klenwell/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/bin/python
```